# How to fetch links of webpage after searching for particular keyword?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium web driver using java.

What I have Tried:

1. Fetch google link
2. Search for a keyword "Selenium"
3. Click on each result and open every link in a new tab.

I tried to fetch all links but I am getting all unwanted links. I just have to fetch the resulted links.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant [XPath query](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727) to filter out only "interesting" links (without eventual [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) suggestions) would be something like

```
//div[@class='r']/a[not(@class='fl')]
```

Once you fetch the links into a collection you can use [window.open()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) function in order to open each suggestion in a new tab:

```
driver.executeScript("window.open(\"" + link.getAttribute("href") + "\");")
```

Full code just in case:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://google.com");
WebElement searchInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']"));
searchInput.clear();
searchInput.sendKeys("Selenium 3");
searchInput.submit();

List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='r']/a[not(@class='fl')]"));

links.forEach(link -> driver.executeScript("window.open(\"" + link.getAttribute("href") + "\");"));
driver.quit();
```